# Stop floating point operations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm displaying a text value and if by coincidence that text value happens to be numeric, then JavaScript displays it with a decimal .0.

Q: How do I write:

```
if (X is numeric) {
   $('#Status').text(+X);
} else {
   $('#Status').text(X);
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're getting at here. Do you want to print a `+` plus character in front of a number if it's numeric, otherwise just print whatever `X` has been assigned?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) depending on your needs.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If X is a sting value "9999.0" and you want that to display in your field as "9999", then you need a different solution than you have asked for as you will have to first parse it as a number and then truncated the decimal positions.  Please clarify by specifying a set of input values for X and what output you want to show.  Be very specific about whether the inputs are strings or actual javascript numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeof` to determine the type of value that a variable stores:

```
if (typeof(X) == 'number') {
   $('#Status').text(+X);
} else {
   $('#Status').text(X);
}
```

The cool thing about `typeof` is that it always returns a string so even if the variable you are checking is not set you will just get the string `undefined`.

Here are some good docs for `typeof`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Unfortunately, it's returning "string" even though the value is: "9990.0"

Comment: You can parseInt(x, 10); that boy right there... even though I don't fully grasp what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, the answer here doesn't mention that typeof is an operator, not a method, try using it like this: `if(typeof X ==='number')` and parseInt will spit out NAN if it's... Not A Number and your typeof will fail.